# How do I listen to a cloud firestore stream in iOS (works fine on Android)?

Tags: ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I can successfully read and write to a cloud firestore database from within my app.  However, when running on an iOS simulator (or real device) I cannot listen to a stream for realtime changes to a document through Riverpod or standard StreamBuilder.  No errors or exceptions are thrown when listening to the stream.  The stream exists, it just doesn't have data in it.  This problem DOES NOT exist when running on an Android emulator.

StreamProvider

```
final athletePosStreamProvider = StreamProvider<GPSPoint>((ref) {
  final _fsDB = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  print('Provider is active');

  return _fsDB.collection('Athlete1').doc('currentPosition').snapshots().map((document) {
    print('stream data found');
    return GPSPoint.fromFSMap(document.data());
  });
});
```

Stream listen:

```
final athletePos = Provider<GPSPoint>((ref) {
  GPSPoint _curPos;

  print('athletePos is active');

  Stream _docStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Athlete1').doc('currentPosition').snapshots();

  if (_docStream.isBroadcast == true) {
    print('Stream is broadcasting');
  }

  _docStream.listen((event) {
    print('athletePos stream event received');
    _curPos = GPSPoint.fromFSMap(event.data());
  });

  return _curPos;
});
```

In both scenarios the first print statement fires, but the second print statement never fires on iOS.  It will work correctly on Android.

```
pubspec.yaml    
cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3+1
flutter_riverpod: ^0.12.1
```

flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.24.0-10.2.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H15 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.24.0-10.2.pre at /Users/sgalway/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 022b333a08 (11 days ago), 2020-11-18 11:35:09 -0800
    • Engine revision 07c1eed46b
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-29.10.beta)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/sgalway/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.2, Build version 12B45b
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 48.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.1.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.3
    • Dart plugin version 201.7846.93

[✓] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.16.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro (mobile) • 21B0C3BA-D8B9-4AF2-81A5-FC8176E49F24 • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-2 (simulator)
    • Web Server (web)       • web-server                           • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 86.0.4240.198

• No issues found!
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are using a listen operation here.  If you want to return a single result from this function, you should use `get()` instead of `snapshots()`.  It return a future that you can await for your document.

Comment: Using get() works fine.  However, I am trying to listen to real time updates to this document.  Listen doesn't work, neither does StreamBuilder, or StreamProvider.  This was the lowest common denominator I could think of.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to listen for a single value, return it, then continue listening for values that aren't going to go anywhere.  You can only return a single value from a function, then it's done.

Comment: I'm not arguing that this is the best way to do anything. My point is that this provider is the lowest common denominator. I can't even get the initial data in the cloud firestore document to enter the stream despite the stream stating that it is broadcasting. I have edited to include a StreamProvider, same behavior.